# Py2exe missing lxml parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, exe, py2exe

I'm trying to make an exe file from my Python project. The problem is that when I run exe file it raises error. Here is the content of the log file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "gui.py", line 12, in __init__
  File "Body.pyc", line 13, in __init__
  File "Connection.pyc", line 31, in get_auth_with_session
  File "milBin.pyc", line 26, in getSoup
  File "bs4\__init__.pyc", line 152, in __init__
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

`milBin` is an imported library in which I have imported `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.
I've already tried to put "bs4"into options->py2exe->includes but nothing changed.

Do you've any idea whats wrong please?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes I know, but it is not a module neither, isn't it? I tried to put "lxml" into includes after your contribution but the problem is still the same.

Comment: It is a module but there is a bit more to installing lxml than just installing the python bindings. Have you specified lxml as the parser in the code somehwere?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  Yes I have. There is 'soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')' in the getSoup method.

Comment: Then unless you want to satisfy the dependency, remove the  'lxml'

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Will it works properly? You mean that I should change  'soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')' to  'soup = BeautifulSoup(page)'?

Comment: different parsers behave differently, sometimes lxml works better and sometimes not but often the default parser is good enough